# Is there algorthm for 2 way 2D plane transformation based on 3 points and angle?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, transformation

So I have such structure: 3 points  (X, Y) BAC and knowledge that in real 3d world BAC angle is 90 degrees.So an image would look like that:

[image]

And what we want to get at first is :

[image]

than we wanna add some stuff like 2 parallel lines

[image]

and what I need next is some formula for somehow shrinking image back to its original view but now with added elements.

So what formulas do I need?

Comment: How did you got the second view from the first one?

Comment: this are scetch 2d drowings - not the real problem=)

Comment: This looks more like a question for math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

You need more info. Like the focal distance. As posed, you have an infinity of solutions to your problem.

Comment: hmmm... any papers\docs proving your point? Because if you are right I will be waaary sad=)

Comment: I mean look at this 3d plane - http://www.flashloaded.com/flashcomponents/3dplane/example3.html .

Comment: this is orthogonal perspective. Not 3 point perspective. The problem is different in this case.